# RDS PostgreSQL: General error: 7 SSL error: invalid key length

Tags: postgresql, amazon-web-services, ssl, networking, rds

Sometimes I catch an error from RDS PostgreSQL.

SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 7 SSL error: invalid key length

Usually it works fine, but sometimes the error.

What could it be? Any ideas?

- Engine: PostgreSQL 9.4.1
- Certificate Authority: rds-ca-2015 (Mar 5, 2020)
- Instance Class: db.m3.medium
- Storage Type: General Purpose (SSD)
- IOPS: disabled
- Storage: 100 GB
- Encryption Enabled: No
- DB Instance Status: available
- Multi AZ: No

**Updated 2016-01-18**

A SQL request does not matter, I catch the error with different requests, usually primitive. And I don't see any relationship with the SQL request.

I noticed, that it happens when SQL requests have a delay:

- <- Request from PayPal Webhook Event
- -> SQL requests (everything fine)
- -> Request to PayPal REST API for validation (everything fine)
- -> SQL requests (catch the error)

I cannot understand, it's only for AWS / RDS or someone catch it in other cases?

**Updated 2016-01-27**

From error/postgresql.log

LOG: could not receive data from client: Connection reset by peer

When I'm trying execute a query again I'm getting another error:

SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 7 no connection to the server

Reconnecting does not help, I have the same error "no connection to the server"

---

The script made 50 attempts during the day and in the end the script has worked without the error.

Seems the error related with network or connecting (PDO connecting, PHP-FPM, PHP 5.6, SSL)

Comment: Sounds like a network issue.

Comment: I have the same issue. I can reproduce it 100% of the time by running one of our scripts but I haven't pinpointed the exact query or whether it's actually caused by a query and not something else

Comment: Can you describe how you can reproduce it? I have the error after receiving PayPal notification after payment by a customer. Using PayPal REST API.

Comment: Same issue with (PDO connecting, PHP-FPM, PHP 7.0, SSL) on Postgresql 9.4 RDS when I run long SQL queries

Answer (score 3):

Same issue here with Paypal, I turned off the `sslmode` in the PostgreSQL connection pool (internal network)

`sslmode=disable`

```
dsn = 'pgsql:host=host.com;port=5432;dbname=postgres;sslmode=disable'
```

Answer (score 0):

**TLDR;**

If you are using OpenSSL or anything related to it and PHP < 7.1, turning off SSL for Postgres might solve your problem.

**non-TLDR;**

Had same issue with custom framework, Postgres 9.3 on AWS VM and a legacy PHP 5.3.

Worked for 3 years w/o any problems then all of a sudden a simple select started throwing this error without any **relevant** changes to code/configuration. It wasn't the longest query we have (char count) and it wasn't the query that took a long time to execute.

While SSL was off in Postgres `pg_hba.conf`, explicitly disabling it in DSN: `sslmode=disable` (see @Gergo Bacskai answer) did help and the error did not return.

So after a deeper investigation what seems to be the cause is this bug: https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=69524

We have started using [phpseclib](https://github.com/phpseclib/phpseclib) when integrating with 3rd party service and it probably uses `openssl_pkey_get_public` or some alternative to it and that's the moment we started receiving these errors.